# From a community stand point, is it worth me answering old unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion

Often I take a look through the unanswered questions and start to answer them only to realise it's a year or more old and subsequently, I abandon answering them.

From a community stand point is it preferable if I answer old questions or would it be better to leave them in the graveyard,  because most likely the person to have asked them has abandoned them.

Comment: +1 for the question, but I can't see a graveyard. Some of the oldest answers I've ever written still are attracting lots of readers, bring upvotes and I even rework them from time to time.

Answer (score 19):

Answers are not written for the asker only. That would be private support. They are for everyone with the same problem. So, yes, write answers to old questions, if they are good and interesting.

Answer (score 12):

Obligatory:

[image]

Comment: http://xkcd.com/979/ -- alt text = "All long help threads should have a sticky globally-editable post at the top saying 'DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far ...'"

Answer (score 6):

Answers benefit the community, regardless of the question's age. If you have information to add, or a possible new alternative response, then by all means answer away.